# What settings does the Ubuntu upgrade tool change during the upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04?

Tags: upgrade, 21.10, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

I am talking about this upgrade tool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz which I am sure the `do-release-upgrade` uses to upgrade to 22.04 from 21.10. I found it in https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release.

During the upgrade, what I have observed is:

1. Updates *sources.list*.
2. Disables third-party repositories to avoid errors with them (can be enabled again after the upgrade).
3. Runs `apt update`
4. Upgrades all the packages using `apt`: `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`
5. Has a list called *demoted.cfg* (which is a list of packages that are not needed to the newer Ubuntu version and are meant to be deleted if they aren't automatically installed, etc.). Gets the packages in the list, checks which of them are manually installed, and combines them to the list of `apt autoremove`, and removes all of them after asking you.
6. **Also removes the Firefox that was installed using `apt`. Or more clearly: it removes packages listed in *dep2snap.cfg (and installs the snap version?).*** Somewhere around these steps.
7. Reboots the system

Are there any other steps here that I am missing? I need to know as I need to revert any unexpected changes to the system.
**Example**: *Changes to the system that helps the system to be stable during the upgrade. But aren't needed after the upgrade.*

**Note:** All the .cfg files mentioned above are in the upgrade tool that `do-release-upgrade` uses. Which I have listed above.

Comment: You can prevent a lot of unexpected issues by reading the [22.04 Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668). The migration of Firefox from deb to snap (#6), for example, is clearly listed in the release notes.

Comment: @user535733, I am also asking for details about the usual things that is always changed during the `do-release-upgrade` to any newer Ubuntu version. So, I am sure those things wouldn't be mentioned in the release notes (although the release notes are pretty helpful) Such as disabling the third-party repos. To avoid making this question too broad, I only asked for details about the Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade tool. I hope you get my point here.

Comment: @user535733 reading the release notes is very helpful though, I agree.

Comment: In that case, the only step I see you missing is updating snaps (which doesn't seem terribly relevant). There's not much secret sauce to a release-upgrade; seems like you have identified the steps of the sequence. The developers try to make the process transparent (it aids troubleshooting).